# Does msync() write to file only changed pages or wholly cached buffer?

Tags: c, linux, posix, mmap, memory-mapped-files

I use a POSIX-function `mmap()` in Linux. But when I do `msync()`, then does it write cached buffer to a file wholly, or somehow it is noted somewhere which pages have changed, and which did not, and writes to the file only changed - i.e. does `msync()` write to file only changed pages or cached buffer wholly?

Suppose if we work with file of 1 GB by using `mmap()`, read it all, ie through a lot of page-fault raised in memory of the entire file. Then we changed only one byte, and called `msync()`, then it will begin to record the whole 1GB to a file or somehow determine the page you want changed and will only keep it, and **how it is defined - how does it do this?**?

Comment: This answer seems more to the point :
http://stackoverflow.com/a/15853757/976686

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`msync` does what you want: it will only write pages which have actually been modified. Actually, `msync` is largely a no-op on Linux or any system with a proper virtual memory and page cache system; `read` will immediately see anything written to the `mmap`ped pages, even without `msync`. It's largely an analog of `fsync`, but with a memory address range rather than a file descriptor as its argument. One other observable effect is that it causes the file modification time to be updated.

Comment: Thanks! But how he does it, how it determines that the writing was made to memory, each time the memory write then an interrupt occurs?

Comment: You say that `msync` is a no-op, and then that `msync` is the analog of `fsync`. The latter, although not what people typically expect that `msync` does, is certainly not no-op. Did you mean that `msync` is no-op for the purpose of propagating the writes to an mmaped region to the rest of the system?

Comment: @user4815162342: In terms of observable behavior on a system without physical failures, `fsync` is a no-op.

Comment: @Alex: Yes, and that's the whole point of `mmap`. Initially, all of the mapped pages are simply references to the corresponding pages in the file on disk; if they're present in memory at all, they're read-only. On the first write access, a page fault occurs and the kernel converts the page to a writable one and marks it dirty so that it will be written back to disk.

Comment: That might be true (if one doesn't count execution time as *observable behavior*), but irrelevant because you wrote that "`msync` is largely a no-op on Linux or any system with a proper virtual memory and page cache system," which is a much stronger claim. I'm not trying to argue semantics here, but to make sure that I understand what you actually *meant* by that part of the answer (the end of my comment ventures a guess).

Comment: What I *meant* is that there's a traditional misunderstanding that `msync` is a required part of using `mmap` for writable shared maps, and that writes might be missed/lost if `msync` is not called (even under normal system operation without hardware failures). This is not the case. `msync` is mainly just a means of ensuring data consistency on disk (in the event of hardware failure), but it does have other subtle effects.

Comment: @R..   "On the first write access, a page fault occurs and the kernel converts the page to a writable one and marks it dirty so that it will be written back to disk." Ok. But what will happen on the second write access, when page already in memory and page-fault does not occur, and will not write to disk? Does it mean that after second write access we need to use `msync()`?

Comment: No. When the kernel writes the page to disk, it will be converted back to read-only and the process repeats.

Comment: OK, that's what I thought you were saying.

Comment: @R.. Thanks! A little clarification, even if page already buffered in RAM, but marked as read-only, and then we write to this memory then will occurs interrupt (page-fault)?